# Curve approximation by some known points on the curve

Tags: approximation

I want to approximate a curve by some known points on the curve.
I can choose these point.
My curve is shown as below:

[image: Efficiency-power curve]

I have to use such a equation:

```
f(x) = a1x^1 + a2x^2 + a3x^3 + a4x^4
```

1) Is it a proper equation for my approximation ?
2) In my case, I should consider P as a and Eta as x?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your criterion for "proper approximation"? It might heavily depends on purposes that what is the proper approximation.

Comment: I need this curve for efficiency curve of an inverter. I already have the curve but I cannot use all the points in my program. 
I do not want it to be very accurate but to have a curve which is close to the real curve.

Comment: In the formula for $f$, replace $x$ with $P_1$, and $f$ with $\eta_1$; this gives you a linear equation relating the four unknowns, $a_1,\dots,a_4$. Then use $P_2$ and $\eta_2$ to get a second equation. Then get similarly a third and a fourth equation. Now you have 4 equations for the 4 unknwons; you can solve, and you're done. A quicker way is to look up "Lagrange interpolation" and use the formulas you will find.

Comment: As long as you just interpolate, it seems that a  polynomial would be a good idea. But use all the data points and perform a polynomial fit. Do not forget to check that the generated polynomial is really continuous (no extremum in the range).

Comment: Thank you all very much and my special thank to Gerry Myerson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rough approximation is enough for your use as you commented, then [Lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) will suit your purpose.

If the number of known points increases in future and you wanted to calculate a fitting curve as number of points increases, then [Newton polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) may suit your purpose better since it doesn't waste computations which was done before.

In the formula for f, replace x with P1, and f with η1; this gives you a linear equation relating the four unknowns, a1,…,a4. Then use P2 and η2 to get a second equation. Then get similarly a third and a fourth equation. Now you have 4 equations for the 4 unknwons; you can solve, and you're done. A quicker way is to look up "Lagrange interpolation" and use the formulas you will find. –  Gerry Myerson

Comment: Thank you Taro and Gerry Myerson.